# Gatsby 5 - get fileAbsolutePath for a node

Tags: graphql, gatsby, mdx

After migrating my project to Gatsby 5 I'm no longer able to access `fileAbsolutePath` on nodes returned by this query:

```
allMdx {
  nodes {
    id
    frontmatter {
      name
      type
    }
    fileAbsolutePath // Does not exist
  }
}
```

My understanding is that the schema has changed.
Unable to find relevant information regarding where to find the respective data.

I tried:

```
allMdx {
  nodes {
    id
    frontmatter {
      name
      type
    }
    file {
      absoluteParth
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm seeing this error:

```
gatsby-plugin-local-search - The provided GraphQL query contains errors. The index will not be created. Cannot query field "file" on type "Mdx".

GraphQLError: Cannot query field "file" on type "Mdx".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [gatsby-plugin-mdx](https://internal.contentFilePath%09The%20absolute%20path%20to%20the%20MDX%20file%20(useful%20for%20passing%20it%20to%20?__contentFilePath%20query%20param%20for%20layouts).%20Equivalent%20to%20the%20absolutePath%20on%20File%20nodes.),
alternative to `fileAbsolutePath` is

`internal.contentFilePath` The absolute path to the MDX file (useful for passing it to ?__contentFilePath query param for layouts). Equivalent to the absolutePath on File nodes.